# iOS and Cocos2d - Play sound once in game loop

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is more of a general "best practice" question, so I don't really have an example. I'm just trying to figure out how people usually approach this.
Let's say I have a mainGameLoop method, scheduled to be called 60 times a second. In this method, I have all the logic for the current scene. Now, I want to play a sound effect using SimpleAudioEngine when a certain state occurs.
The issue is, once this state occurs, it stays like that for a while, which means my sound effect will be rapidly played over and over again until the state changes (after all, we're inside the game loop).
My usual solution for this, is to use booleans to play the effect only once. Problem is, I am now facing a larger number of different states and effects, which means quite a lot of booleans.

I was wondering if there's a better way people usually use when playing sound effects in the game loop.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "state changed" event. Whenever the state changes to "on" the sound plays. Since you have to record this state change there's hardly any way around providing a boolean to record each state.

Of course you wouldn't code each state separately. Let's say you have 100 game objects (ie fruits) and each fruit plays a different sound when collected, you'd have a fruit class with a "fruitType" variable. When a fruit is picked up, you can:

- check if this fruit type is already "carried"
- play a sound if it is not
- select the sound based on fruitType

Comment: Good idea! Moving the sound state to another object skipped my mind. Thinking about it, if these sounds are not related to any object (only to a certain "state"), I can create a class that holds a playOnce method, initialize it with a sound effect and bool flag, and call it from within the loop. I can also use a reset method from outside the loop to make it playable again.